# Programming to Interfaces is awesome and I agree 100% but would it always be possible?

Tags: java

Here is an example:

A concrete implementation may have some specific behavior like implementation of `ArrayList` has `ensureCapacity()` which is not applicable to `LinkedList`.

```
//programming to interface not implementation
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("hi");
list.add("hello");

// now I need to use some method from ArrayList e.g. ensureCapacity() 
list.ensureCapacity(); // can't as list is List with no ensureCapacity()
```

**Edited to include more details:**

2nd example scenario:

```
List list=new LinkedList();
Iterator li=list.listIterator();// Program to interface rule
li.add("Hi");// NOT allowed as add() is part of ListIterator
```

Q1. If we are supposed to 'program to interface', what is the need of specific methods like "add()" in ListIterator and ArrayList?

Q2. Does "Programming to an interface" mean "apply this concept as much as you can but you can't always"?

Q3. Would it be better to use ListIterator instead of Iterator?

Comment: Since not all classes implement an interface/interfaces, no.

Comment: Just cast that `((ArrayList)list).ensureCapacity();`

Comment: You already know the answer, since you provided an example where it isn't possible.

Comment: an interface is just a basic construct that tells you what the class implementing the interface is able to perform (based on the method names). The term how it is achived depends on the implementing class. Since the `List` interface isn´t meant to ensure the capacity of it´s containing array, it´s just not part of the method structure of this interface.

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan then, it would go against the principles of loose coupling and changing  new ArrayList() to new LinkedList() in future would break the code because of this ((ArrayList)list) type casting. So, we would miss the whole point of List list = new ArrayList();

Comment: @Akki If you want to use the methods in concrete implementation you should use the Concrete class itself. You cant do that with interfaces. Could you specify the broken rule.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of using an interface (`List`) instead of a class (`ArrayList`), in your case, is that you don't really care about the implementation. At the creation you pick a type (or whoever provides the list to you does that) after that, you don't bother about the type, your code will work with all `List`s.

In your case however, you use a mechanism specific for `ArrayList`. Your code will work fine without, because `ensureCapacity()` is just a means of telling the `ArrayList` that it can be more efficient if it reserves it's capacity in one go (instead of steadily increasing). You now have the following options:

1. Don't go for the optimization, in most cases you don't need it, as `ArrayList` will do a pretty good job without the hint.
2. Require `ArrayList` making it more efficient to use, but less flexible, because your code only accepts `ArrayList` even in cases where performance would not matter.
3. Finally you could use `instanceof ArrayList`, and only if an ArrayList is provided you do the optimization. This is not very clean, but sometimes you have to do this in order to provide the best experience to the users of your class. This can be the case if you publish a widely used API.

In most cases item 1 is your best pick. If this code is not used in many cases, but operates on something you know can (or will) always be an `ArrayList` because it is created in the same class/method AND you need the performance item 2 is a good pick.

So the conclusion is: no it is not always possible nor desirable. The idea behind it is that you use the interfaces (or super class) that is as generic as possible, giving the user of your code most freedom.

EDIT: note that the `ensureCapacity` really is only needed for lists with millions of items, as ArrayList scales with increasing increments. In most cases when it needs more room it will at least double the internal array, as shown below (note that this is from the Oracle implementation in Java 8):

```
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1); // This more than doubles the size
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Please note that ensureCapacity() here is just an example( and not for optimization ). There may be some other methods as well.

Comment: @Akki perhaps my answer is focussed a bit too much on this example (mostly because I was curious enough myself to look up the precise growth stragetegy), but the general tradeoff when deciding what level of interface / superclass to use is the same in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The question here should be : Why do you need to call the specific ensure capacity ?

If you try to answer this question you will notice yourself that the cases where you have to use this specific methods are rare and that you can use interface, lets say 99% of the time, unless you are doing something very specific in some exceptional situation.

*The rule program to interface rather than to implementation is a good practice and don't see any hurdle to follow it unless in very exceptional situations.*

Comment: So, would it be correct to assume that sometimes ( 1% of the time ), the rule 'program to interface' may not be possible to apply?

Comment: As already said in my answer it all depends on the context, anyway I can only see exceptional situations in which you have to work with the concrete implementation .

Answer (score 0):

Methods specific to concrete implementations are not shareable across the interface.

**Example**
That is why `Map` is not using `Collections` interface. Because most of the method in collections are not suitable for `Map`.

`Car` is an interface. How to do expect car to have a `airbag` feature which is specific to a concrete implementation `Ferrari`, which may not be available in a brand `X`. But all will have the properties `Tyres` in its interface.

If you want to make use of interfaces you should follow the standards. Else go for concrete implementations.